# How to get formatted text draft-js

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

Using the below code i am getting plaintext but i want formatted text
on button click

```
<input onClick={() => {alert(this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent().getPlainText());}} type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful for you:
https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/how-draft-js-represents-rich-text-data-eeabb5f25cf2

You can use **convertToRaw** function. It returns a structured text result that you can then process as you like. The idea is — Draft.js doesn't have any assumptions about the output format so you can really fine tune your output.